# D3 <path> has NAN values in its coordinates

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I'm attempting to follow this example: [Line Chart: bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245), but I keep getting an error like:

> d3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,450LNaN,425.96810933940776LNaN,386.2186788154896LNaN,373.917995444>1913LNaN,375.28473804100224LNaN,379.0432801822323LNaN,368.5649202733485LNa>N,368.4510250569475LNaN...

I've already solved lots of wrong (outdated?) parts of this example, but I can't crack this one. I've read about time objects vs. formatting them as strings causing similar problems, but no matter which way I format d.date, my output always has NANs in it.

JSON:

```
 var lineData = [
{"date":"24-Apr-07","close":93.24},
{"date":"25-Apr-07","close":95.35},
{"date":"26-Apr-07","close":98.84}...
```

JS:

```
var parseTime = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
...

svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

function type(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}
```

Full code on Codepen: http://codepen.io/SammyJ/pen/qZoEdO

Comment: Where are you using your type function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `type` function here.

You need to apply the type function to your raw data:

```
var data = lineData.map(type);
```

This was done in the loading stage in the sample which you took out:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
```

Documentation:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

> Note that the values themselves are always strings; they will not be automatically converted to numbers. JavaScript may coerce strings to numbers for you automatically (for example, using the + operator). By specifying an accessor function, you can convert the strings to numbers or other specific types, such as dates:

Also, your domain is taking in the new data so it does not need to reprocess the data, hence these two lines

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseTime(d.date); }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.close; }));
```

need to be changed to:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));
```

See the updated example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNjgEw

Comment: Awesome. So a big part of my confusion was how to use a local JSON object instead of external data and d3.tsv() or d3.csv()... calling type within data.map() is the leap I hadn't made. Thank you!

Comment: map is a useful function for JavaScript, check out the documentation and examples for more details on how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map